# SharePoint WebPart Type Question

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I want to do some stuff to WebParts based on the type of WebPart is being passed to a method.
I'm finding that I'm doing:

```
if(obj is Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart)
...
else if (obj is SummaryLinkWebPart)
```

It smells funny to keep doing this for all WebParts. Is there a design pattern that I should be using instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to access members specific to a certain type then there really isn't any *superclean* way of doing so. If you want, you can use the `as` operator to achieve the same effect as above:

```
wp = obj as Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart;
if(wp != null)
   ...
```